# JSPM / SystemJS can't find source-map-support.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, source-maps, jspm

First I have to say, I am struggling having JSPM + SystemJS + TypeScript + Angular working all together. Posting all my files here would be a bit too much, but what I can say is that I can import standard JS files compiled through the default transpiler "babel" and that works. As soon as I try to work with my .ts files, it breaks.

I am having something like this in my config.js:

```
  typescriptOptions: {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "tsconfig": false
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "app/*": "src/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "src": {
      "main": "index",
      "format": "system",
      "defaultExtension": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

When I try to load it through System.import('./src/index.ts'), I get an error "source-map-support.js 404 (Not Found)" in the console. I am not using source-map or anything related to it, I tried to install it through jspm but it doesn't help, I googled and Stackoverflowed about it but nothing comes up. I have no idea how to debug this.

Do you have any idea? I am not even looking for the perfect solution, but somewhere to start looking would be awesome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while debugging the same problem, and came across this issue: https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/issues/160 (the comment by @aluanhaddad)

I can confirm that it worked for me to manually install `source-map-support`

`jspm install npm:source-map-support`

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you :)